# Extract input element value from current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I'm trying to extract the values of input tags, but because the page hasn't been submitted yet, I get null for each value.  I know this is normal behavior, but is there a way to extract them without submitting the page?

My code below extracts the input tags but I get null for the values:

So here's my content.js:

```
var elements = new Array("input");
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    var current = document.getElementsByTagName(elements[i]);
    if(current.length>0)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y<current.length; y++)
        {
            output += "&" + current[y].id + "=" + current[y].value;
        }
    }
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: output});
```

and here's my background.js:

```
var output2 = "";
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    output2 += request.data;
});
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com?" + output2}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"}, function() {
            sendMessage();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't have to submit the page to extract the values of the input elements in javascript

Comment: Right, so how do I get the values?

Comment: Problem seems to be in different place. Show more code.

Comment: The code you posted looks ok. Try putting it in a JSFiddle

Comment: After update: still working. you should share your extension.

Comment: I can't test it with JSFiddle because I need the value of what's entered by the user on the current tab, for each input tag.  So I still don't know what's wrong.